# Solaar failing to show up

Tags: logitech-unifying

I have installed solaar by entering `pip install solaar`. But when I run `solaar --version`, I end up getting `bash: /usr/bin/solaar: No such file or directory`.

I've been searching around on the Internet, to no avail.

I have run `lsusb` to show that I do have a logitech unifying receiver plugged in.

[image]

Additionally, these are the folders I have

[image]

I have indeed found `~/.local/bin/solaar`

[image]

Comment: Check if you have `/bin/solaar` or `/usr/local/bin/solaar`. Not sure what target directory `pip install` uses these days.

Comment: Some more info here: https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/installation (section "Installing Solaar Using Pip"): It might be in `~/.local/bin/solaar`.

Comment: @HuHa  Thank you for the response.  I uploaded a screenshot of the folders I have on my computer.  I dont see `/bin/solaar` or `/.local/bin/solaar` I assume `/.local` is supposed to be hidden?

Comment: @HuHa  yes, thats where I had the file `solaar`  I uploaded the picture above.

Comment: What was wrong with package from [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=solaar) installed by `sudo apt-get install solaar` ?

Comment: @N0rbert after installing it by running `sudo apt-get install solaar`, i tried `--window=show` but it said `--window=show: command not found`.  I tried opening it manually but i don't see any device showing up on the list..

Comment: See my full installation and setup instructions here: [How do I install and configure the latest version of `solaar` to manage my Logitech wireless mouse or keyboard on Linux Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1390784/327339).

Comment: Same here. Won't launch after the upgrade to 22.04.1 LTS. I have installed it with `sudo apt-get install solaar`.

Comment: I can run it only with `sudo solaar`.